# How to fix Cygwin error: while loading shared libraries: cygproj-13.dll: cannot open shared object file?

Tags: windows, cygwin, cdo-climate

I have tried to run cdo sinfon command on Windows 7 cygwin -x86_64 environment but have consistently encountered with the following error. I have installed all required packages like gcc, gcc-gfortran, openssl, openssh, curl, zlib, netcdf, libnetcdf-devel, udunits-devel, proj-devel etc. I have run the following commands---

SID@SID-PC ~
$ cd /cygdrive/C/demo/tas

SID@SID-PC /cygdrive/C/demo/tas
$ PATH="$PATH:.:"

SID@SID-PC /cygdrive/C/demo/tas
$ cdo sinfon Ind.nc
C:/demo/tas/cdo.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygproj-13.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

SID@SID-PC /cygdrive/C/demo/tas
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.1 SID-PC 3.1.4(0.340/5/3) 2020-02-19 08:49 x86_64 Cygwin

Answer (score 2):

Asking the right tool

```
Usage: cygcheck [-v] [-h] PROGRAM
...
  -p, --package-query  search for REGEXP in the entire cygwin.com package
               repository (requires internet connectivity)
...
```

you have

```
 $ cygcheck -p cygproj-13.dll
Found 3 matches for cygproj-13.dll
libproj13-5.0.1-1 - libproj13: The PROJ Cartographic Projections Software
libproj13-5.1.0-1 - libproj13: The PROJ Cartographic Projections Software
libproj13-5.2.0-1 - libproj13: The PROJ Cartographic Projections Software
```

You need to install the `libproj13` package.

Comment: how to add `libproj13` ? I have same issue on this

Comment: https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-net.html#setup-packages

Comment: This solution worked for me after receiving `rsync.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cyglz4-1.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`